# How can I specify the weights to be used in a Keras model (in R)?

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to manually set the weights for a network with 1 input node (plus a bias node) and 2 nodes in the hidden layer.  How can I do this?

Starter code:

```
library(keras)

model <- keras_model_sequential()

wts = list(matrix(c(1, 1), ncol=1), matrix(c(1, 1), ncol=1))
model <-  layer_dense(
  object = model, input_shape = 1L, use_bias = TRUE, units = 2L, activation = 'sigmoid', 
  weights = wts
)
```

This gives "ValueError: Layer weight shape (1, 2) not compatible with provided weight shape (2, 1)"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the trick to making this work is to use an *array* to specify the bias weights.

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
wts = list(matrix(c(1, 1), nrow=1), array(c(1, 1)))
model <-  layer_dense(
  object = model, input_shape = 1L, use_bias = TRUE, units = 2L, activation = 'sigmoid', weights = wts
)

get_weights(model)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1
```